# how to filter multiple array value with for loop in php?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

Output must be "This is a testing string sample". it is correct for small array filter with index value if  filter array value are more than 100 values we can't assign static index number.How can be loop to filter to my base array. i know can use array_diff but i just learn how work with for loop.

```
<?php

$arr = array("This","is","testing","a","string",";","sample");
$filter = array(";","a");

    for($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
        if($arr[$i] == $filter[0] || $arr[$i] == $filter[1]){
             continue;
        }
      echo "$arr[$i] ";
    }

?>
```

Comment: You are looking for in_array($arr[$i], $filter);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could filter multiple values from an array using `array_diff`. For this case, you don't need an loop.

```
$filtered = array_diff($arr, $filter);
```

In general, there's an function, called `array_filter` to filter values from an array given a predicate.

```
$filtered = array_filter($arr, function ($item) use ($filter) {
    return !in_array($item, $filter);
});
```

To print your result, you could just use join to combine the whole array with a "glue".

```
echo join(' ', $filtered);
```

To fix your example, you could also loop over your filter and use `continue 2`, to continue the outer loop. But this is very bad practice and leads to unreadable code. So don't do this! A better solution would be an "found" flag and another check after the inner loop, if the flag is set...

```
for($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($filter); $j++) {
        if ($arr[$i] == $filter[$j]) {
            continue 2;
        }
    }
    echo "$arr[$i] ";
}
```

Comment: can be possible with for loop? just want to know bro

Comment: @MinKoKo thats possible, but you really shouldn't do this. The code becames unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Use [in_array](http://php.net/in_array)

```
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    if (in_array($item, $filter) {
        continue;
    }
    echo $item, ' ';
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro. Can possible with for nested loop?